# AVERAGEIFS with OR conditions

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I've got a series of blood pressure measurements. I want to determine the average pressures during the day and during the night.

[image: Blood pressure data]

The first half of the problem is trivial:

```
=AVERAGEIFS(B17:B71;A17:A71;">="&I16;A17:A71;"<="&I17)
```

builds the average over all cells in column B ("Sys") if the corresponding value of column A ("Time") is greater than 7:00 and less than 22:00 (those time values are in cells I16/17).

My problem is how to calculate the average for the hours *outside* that range. I would have to check if the time is smaller than 7:00 *or* greater than 22:00, but `AVERAGEIFS` conditions are combined by `AND`.

I obviously can't use `NOT()` because I would have to apply it to the result of both comparisons at once, and there doesn't seem to be a way to do that.

Conditional highlighting is not a problem as you can see above - there I can enter several conditions that are tested sequentially, effectively giving me an `OR` operator...

Is there maybe a function I can use to get a subset of cells from a range that I can apply another function to? I'll probably need something like that anyway when I want to determined blood pressure maxima and minima for day/night - Excel doesn't have a `MAXIFS()` function...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Googling around a bit, I think I found solutions to both of your problem. For the first part, you can try [adding the booleans for your two conditions](http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/542416-averageifs-possible-do-somehow.html#post2678259) to see if they both are true:

```
=AVERAGE(IF((A17:A71<I16)+(A17:A71>=I17);B17:B71))
```

Note that this is an array-formula, so you must enter it as such (hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> when done entering the formula).

For the second part you do the same, but switch the `AVERAGE`-function with `MAX`:

```
=MAX(IF((A17:A71<=I16)+(A17:A71>I17);B17:B71))
```

I hope this works for you!

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know about array formulas, will have to look into that.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following. It uses the fact that you can extract the daytime measurements to subtract the daytime element from the total, giving the overnight average.

> `= (SUM(B17:B71) - SUMIFS(B17:B71;A17:A71;">="&I16;A17:A71;"<="&I17)) / (COUNT(B17:B71) - COUNTIFS(B17:B71;A17:A71;">="&I16;A17:A71;"<="&I17))`

Answer (score 0):

So far, I've come with the following idea:

I'm using a helper column with the function

```
=IF(AND(A17>=$I$16;A17<$I$17);"Day";"Night")
```

that then contains the string "Day" if the time is during the day, and "Night" otherwise. I can then look at that column with the `AVERAGEIF` function.

Still, that doesn't help me with finding the maximum pressure for all "day values"...